# R: Fit Linear Mixed-Effects Model with GAM (mgcv)

Tags: r, mixed-model, aic, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Imagine a linear mixed effects model with one random intercept:

```
library(lme4)
LMM1 <- lmer(response ~ experience + (1|subject), REML=FALSE, data=train)
```

I'd like to fit a conceptual equivalent using the `mgcv` package, that is:

```
library(mgcv)
LMM2 <- bam(response ~ experience, s(subject, bs='re'), method='ML', data=train)
```

Note that I use the function `bam` which is optimized for big datasets. The summaries of the two models yield the same results w.r.t. the estimated intercept, and effect size, standard deviation and t-value of the fixed effect. However, `AIC(LMM1)` and `AIC(LMM2)` yield different results. Why?

In addition, I'm wondering whether the below listed pairs of models are conceptual equal:

```
Random intercept:
lmer(response ~ experience + (1|subject), data=train)
bam(response ~ experience + s(subject, bs=’re’), data=train)

Random slope:
lmer(response ~ experience + (0+experience|subject), data=train)
bam(response ~ experience + s(experience, subject, bs=’re’), data=train)

Random intercept and random slope:
lmer(response ~ experience + (1+experience|subject), data=train)
bam(response ~ experience + s(subject, bs='re') + s(experience, subject, bs=’re’), data=train)
```

If not, please put me right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those two model definitions should be equivalent. However, you have to be careful comparing likelihood's between software implementations as different constants can often be ignored in the computation; not sure that's the case here but it is something to be aware of. What may be causing differences here is that *mgcv* is adjusting the AIC to account for the selection of the "smoothness parameter" for the random effects terms; here this basically just means choosing the amount of shrinkage, but *mgcv* uses a correction to the AIC for smoothness selection and that could be the cause of the difference.

Of the other model forms, these are all equivalent, **except** for the random slopes and intercepts model. *mgcv* can't fit correlated random effect models and the version of the random slopes and intercepts models you showed has correlated random effects. The `lmer()` version of the model has an additional covariance parameter which will be missing from the `bam()` fit.

You can fit and compare uncorrelated random effects models using the alternate form for `lmer()`:

```
lmer(response ~ experience + (1 | subject) + (0 + experience | subject), 
     data = train)

bam(response ~ experience + s(subject, bs = 're') +
      s(experience, subject, bs = ’re’),
    data = train)
```